# Is there any way to store the trained neural network into memory in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I try to create a speaker recognition system. The training time is so long so I wonder if there is a way I can store the model and load it from the memory when the GUI launchs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save your trained network with

```
save net
```

this will save the network called net as net.mat, you can then load it to the workspace with

```
load net
```

To do your prediction, you can use

`sim(net, inputs)`

Type

```
doc sim
```

for detailed help

(more details on this can be easily found on MATLAB central)